# Android Inputstream read() method never returns -1

Tags: android, inputstream

I have the following code

```
    InputStream iis = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(fileid);
    int c;
    while((c = iis.read())!=-1){
        Log.d("myapp", c+"");
    }
```

But, this code never coming out of the loop, and read() function never returns -1. It always returns an integer.
Is anything wrong with the above code?
My raw text file is very small in size.

Comment: Try to rearrange the condition to `> 0`

Comment: No this is wrong comment, also taking into account the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not that you just have too big file and the logging makes the loop very slow?

Comment: I have this problem too when reading input stream. I use totalReadByte >= File.length() as alternative to come out from the while loop.

Comment: you read the file bytewise and create 1 line of log for each. So 100kB = 102400 lines in log. I guess you really just slow down log so much that you don't see it end.

Comment: @zapl Yes, you are right. Logging slowed the reading process. Thanks for pointing this out.